# Pandas: concatenate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe

```
category    count_sec_target
 3D-шутеры  0.09375
 Cериалы    201.90625
 GPS и ГЛОНАСС  0.015625
 Hi-Tech    187.1484375
 Абитуриентам   0.8125
 Авиакомпании   8.40625
```

and

```
category    count_sec_random
 3D-шутеры  0.369565217
 Hi-Tech    70.42391304
 АСУ ТП,  промэлектроника   0.934782609
 Абитуриентам   1.413043478
 Авиакомпании   14.93478261
 Авто   480.3369565
```

I need to concatenate that And get

```
category    count_sec_target    count_sec_random
 3D-шутеры  0.09375    0.369565217
 Cериалы    201.90625   0
 GPS и ГЛОНАСС  0.015625   0
 Hi-Tech    187.1484375   70.42391304
 Абитуриентам   0.8125   1.413043478
 Авиакомпании   8.40625   14.93478261
 АСУ ТП,  промэлектроника   0    0.934782609
 Авто   0     480.3369565
```

And next I want to divide values in col `(count_sec_target / count_sec_random) * 100%`
But when I try to concatenate df

```
frames = [df1, df1]
df = pd.concat(frames)
I get 
category  count_sec_random  count_sec_target
 0                        3D-шутеры          0.369565               NaN
 1                          Hi-Tech         70.423913               NaN
 2         АСУ ТП,  промэлектроника          0.934783               NaN
 3                     Абитуриентам          1.413043               NaN
 4                     Авиакомпании         14.934783               NaN
```

Also I try `df = df1.append(df2)`
BUt I get wrong result.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe you need to use pd.merge in order to get your desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df3 = pd.concat([d.set_index('category') for d in frames], axis=1).fillna(0)
df3['ratio'] = df3.count_sec_random / df3.count_sec_target
df3
```

[image]

---

***Setup Reference***

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

t1 = """category;count_sec_target
3D-шутеры;0.09375
Cериалы;201.90625
GPS и ГЛОНАСС;0.015625
Hi-Tech;187.1484375
Абитуриентам;0.8125
Авиакомпании;8.40625"""

t2 = """category;count_sec_random
3D-шутеры;0.369565217
Hi-Tech;70.42391304
АСУ ТП,  промэлектроника;0.934782609
Абитуриентам;1.413043478
Авиакомпании;14.93478261
Авто;480.3369565"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t1), sep=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t2), sep=';')

frames = [df1, df2]
```

Comment: Can you say, how can I next divide one column to other?

Comment: and I need to get column `index` at the left

Answer (score 4):

Merge should be appropriate here:

```
df_1.merge(df_2, on='category', how='outer').fillna(0)
```

[image]

---

To get the division output, simply do:

```
df['division'] = df['count_sec_target'].div(df['count_sec_random'])  * 100
```

where: `df` is the merged DF

Comment: I was just going to add this ;-)  Agreed, this is more appropriate.